# Scaling Up A Matrix in R

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, resize

I'm working on a project that involves porting MATLAB code into R, and have run into a bit of trouble with one chunk of code.

What the piece of code does in MATLAB is resizes a mask (just 1s and 0s) to be the same sizes as a much larger set of data that it will be masking. The data that the mask is applied to changes in size, so I can't just set static values for the scaling.

The MATLAB code has a function [resizem](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/resizem.html) that resizes the mask, preserving the only 1s and 0s characteristic.

I've searched (to no avail) for solutions to my problem, but I don't think that my issue plagues many R users (it's a non-traditional use of R). So I was wondering if anyone knew a way to resize a matrix in the same way that resizem does.

For Example:

If I had the array

```
[1,0,1,1,1,
0,0,0,1,1,
1,1,0,0,1]
```

And I wanted to scale it from 3x5 to 7x10 with the 7x10 matrix containing only 1s and 0s like this.

```
 1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1
 1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1
```

How could I approach this with an R function.

Comment: It would help if you (1) linked to the documentation for `resizem` in MATLAB, and (2) provided a detailed description of what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Put it in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: yeah, wasn't sure what I was thinking there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible R implementation of such a function

```
resizem <- function(M, rows,cols) {
    rs <- round(seq(0, rows-1)/(rows-1) * (nrow(M)-1) +1)
    cs <- round(seq(0, cols-1)/(cols-1) * (ncol(M)-1) +1)
    M[rs, ][, cs]
}
```

Here we just require you to specify the number of rows and cols you want in the new matrix. We just use the default nearest neighbor interpolation (resizem has other options). This seems to work with the test data

```
M <- matrix(c(1,0,1,1,1,
    0,0,0,1,1,
    1,1,0,0,1), byrow=T, nrow=3)
resizem(M, 7,10)
```

and that returns

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1     1
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1     1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1     1
[6,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1     1
[7,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1     1
```

Comment: I'll check this when I get back to my computer, but looking at it, I'd say you are a God send. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not immediately obvious to me how this is supposed to work when the rescaled matrix isn't an integer multiple of the size of the original mask, but if it is then you can use a [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product):

```
kronecker(z,matrix(1,nrow=2,ncol=2))
```

This makes a 6x10 matrix.  To make a (3nx5n) matrix, you would use `nrow=n,ncol=n` in the example above.

OK, I see from the linked documentation:

> resizem uses interpolation to resample to a new sample density/cell
>   size. If scale is between 0 and 1, the size of Z is smaller than the
>   size of Z1. If scale is greater than 1, the size of Z is larger. For
>   example, if scale is 0.5, the number of rows and the number of columns
>   will be halved. By default, resizem uses nearest neighbor
>   interpolation.

So this trick will only work in special cases.  But it should be very efficient, and can be used on sparse matrices too ...

Comment: I should have mentioned this above, but I tried this method to no avail. I think because the data that it is reading is of different sizes (which are rarely integer multiples). This may come in handy later in the project though. Thanks.